# Dynamically Change Chart Rate Based on Option Button Selection

Tags: excel, dynamic, charts, range, offset

I have been trying to dynamically change the range of a stacked bar chart to adapt to different selections of three option buttons.  My table is arranged from J1:M14.  The top line contains the headers for each column.  The first column (J) contains a descriptive column.  The actual data is contained between columns K and M.  One selection of the option button results in the range of the data expanding to J1:M15.  So, based on the option button selection, the number of rows in this table increase, but the number of columns remains fixed.

I want to create a stacked bar chart that displays each of the stacked bars for each descriptive label in column J.  With a different selection of the option button, the stacked bar chart will either extend to include the extra label, shrink to remove the extra label, or keep the same length.

What is happening: The range is fixed and will not change.  When I select the option button, the range does not shift based on the data range.

What I have tried: Under formulas-->Name Manager, I have created four new names:

```
1.) DatainColumnK: =OFFSET(Calculations!$K$2,,,COUNTIF(Calculations!$K$2:$K$100,"<>"))
2.) DatainColumnL: =OFFSET(Calculations!$L$2,,,COUNTIF(Calculations!$L$2:$L$100,"<>"))
3.) DatainColumnM: =OFFSET(Calculations!$M$2,,,COUNTIF(Calculations!$M$2:$M$100,"<>"))
4.) DescLabelColJ: =OFFSET(Calculations!$J$2,,,COUNTIF(Calculations!$J$2:$J$100,"<>"))
```

Next, I selected the entire range of the data --> Created a stacked bar chart --> Clicked Select data --> Added three new series in the Legend Entries by editing series and only entering in TabName!DatainColK, TabName!DatainColL, TabName!DatainColM and then editing the axis labels by adding in TabName!DescLabelColJ.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you can convert your data range into a Table, then you can create a name in the Name Manager that refers to the changing data range. [This website](https://analyticsdemystified.com/excel-tips/excel-dynamic-named-ranges-with-tables-never-manually-updating-your-charts/) gives a good look at what to do.

Comment: I tried following the directions from the link and converting my original data to an Excel table, but the problem persists.  This is resulting in a stacked bar chart that has several blank spaces on the end (right side) of the graph when I select an option that has less data than the other options.  I want to eliminate the blank spaces when an option with less data is selected and be able to grow when an option is selected with more data.

Comment: If you can show some sample data and what you're trying to accomplish, that will help to envision what formulas or structure you need.